# Check if a string matches the beginning of a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have many string to match against a regex. Many strings start with the same substring. To speed up my search, I would like to check whether the regex could match a string which begins with the common substring...

###### Example

I have a regex like for instance: `/^(.[3e]|[o0]+)+l+$/` and many strings, like for instance these:

```
...
goo
goober
good
goodhearted
goodly
goods
goody
goof
goofball
google
goon
goose
...
held
helical
helices
helicopter
helipad
heliport
hell
help
hellion
helm
helmet
...
```

Half of the strings start with `goo`: I'd like to test whether `goo` is a valid beginning for a match. It's not (no string starting with `goo` can ever match that regex), thus I'd discard all those words at once.

The other half start with `hel`: I'd like to test whether `hel` is a valid beginning for a match. It is (some strings starting with `hel` may match that regex), thus I proceed testing those strings.

Is there any function to do this with a generic regex, without having to manually re-engineer it?

Comment: The only thing you want to check is whether a string starts with some substring ? Then you don't need a regex, Slice() would be enough.

Comment: No. I need to test if a substring (for instance `goo` or `hel`) is a valid beginning of a regex (for instance `/^(.[3e]|[o0]+)+l+$/`).

Comment: A regex matches what it matches. You could always make other regex instances to just test fragments of the actual texts.

Comment: `goo` at start can never be matched with `^(.[3e]|[o0]+)+l+$` however maybe you are looking for a *negative* [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), something like [`^(?!goo)...`](https://regex101.com/r/mKx5vX/1)

Comment: What is the regex engine? RE2 (Go)?

Answer (score 0):

With the data set given, filtering on the first 3 characters didn't speed up the processing. The overhead of shuffling the data is likely not worth it.

```js
const test = `...
goo
goober
good
goodhearted
goodly
goods
goody
goof
goofball
google
goon
goose
...
held
helical
helices
helicopter
helipad
heliport
hell
help
hellion
helm
helmet
...`;

const re1 = /^(.[3e]|[o0]+)+l+$/;

const t0 = performance.now();

// split the test string into an array
let arr1 = test.split('\n');

// create a set to hold the first three letters of each string in the array
const firstThree = new Set();
arr1.forEach(e => {
  firstThree.add(e.substring(0, 3));
});

// loop through the set
for (const ft of firstThree) {
  // check if the first three characters match the regular expression
  if (!re1.test(ft)) {
    // if not, remove those strings from the array
    arr1 = arr1.filter(e => e.indexOf(ft) !== 0);
  }
}

arr1 = arr1.filter(e => re1.test(e));
const t1 = performance.now();
console.log(`Took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds.`);

console.log(arr1);

const re2 = /^(?:.[3e]|[o0]+)+l+$/mg;

const t2 = performance.now();
const arr2 = [...test.matchAll(re2)];
const t3 = performance.now();
console.log(`Took ${t3 - t2} milliseconds.`);

console.log(arr2[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead test to exclude strings starting with `goo`, and a positive lookahead to consider only strings starting with 'hel', followed by your actual test:

```js
[
  'goo',
  'goober',
  'good',
  'goodhearted',
  'goodly',
  'goods',
  'goody',
  'goof',
  'goofball',
  'google',
  'goon',
  'goose',
  'held',
  'helical',
  'helices',
  'helicopter',
  'helipad',
  'heliport',
  'hell',
  'help',
  'hellion',
  'helm',
  'helmet'
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ' => ' + /^(?!goo)(?=hel)(.[3e]|[o0]+)+l+$/.test(str));
});
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `(?!goo)` -- negative lookahead for `goo`, e.g. no match if found
- `(?=hel)` -- positive lookahead for `hel`
- `(.[3e]|[o0]+)+l+$` -- your existing regex test

See regex tutorial on positive/negative lookahead & lookbehind:
https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex